# Python scale per group to a range

Tags: python, range, scale, group

Python experts, could someone shed me some lights on how to do this?

I have a large dataset, say DF with 'Date' and 'Value' columns (among others). Now, I need to scale the 'Value' column per 'Date' group so that each date has the 'Value' scaled to the range of [-3, 3].

Seems pretty straightforward in Excel but stuck how to implement it in Python.

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Is the dataset a csv file? What format is the dataset and how is it loaded into the script?

Comment: Thanks, ELM, for your attention.  I loaded the data from DB.  Or another way to ask my question is: how to groupby normalize a DF column to a fixed range

Comment: Find the minimum and maximum values of `Value`. Then use the formula `new_value = -3 + 6 * (value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)`

Comment: Thanks much, Barmar.  Yes, I got this in place yesterday but noticed it changed the mean of the distribution from zero to nonzero.  I know I didn't put that requirement in my original post.  Is there a way to do groupby (date) normalization while keeping the normalized scores within the range of [-3, 3]?